# ValueError: Tensor data is null. Run allocate_tensors() first

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantization, tflite, quantization-aware-training

I have a tflite model, then I want to print weights of model, but it can't work. I search lots of information, still can't fix.

```
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_path='/content/drive/MyDrive/non_RR/tflite_qaware_model.tflite')

interpreter.allocate_tensors()

tensor_details = interpreter.get_tensor_details()
for tensor in tensor_details:
    print("Layer Name:", tensor['name'])
    print("Shape:", tensor['shape'])
    weights = interpreter.get_tensor(tensor['index'])
    print("Weights:", weights)
```

Error messages:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-b3ca2c8bc8db> in <cell line: 6>()
      7     print("Layer Name:", tensor['name'])
      8     print("Shape:", tensor['shape'])
----> 9     weights = interpreter.get_tensor(tensor['index'])
     10     print("Weights:", weights)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/interpreter.py in get_tensor(self, tensor_index, subgraph_index)
    874       a numpy array.
    875     """
--> 876     return self._interpreter.GetTensor(tensor_index, subgraph_index)
    877 
    878   def tensor(self, tensor_index):

ValueError: Tensor data is null. Run allocate_tensors() first
```